# Add to cart validation in WooCommerce for a purchase-only product

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, cart, hook-woocommerce

I want to prevent:

- When a certain product is in the cart, no other product should be added
- When there are other products in cart, the certain product should not be added

---

I have a code snippet that restricts the addition of more than one product. It works, but it shows the restriction message every time a 2nd product is added, whichever product this may be. This way there can never be multiple products in the cart.

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'tidaweb_only_one_item_allowed_add_to_cart', 10, 3 );

function tidaweb_only_one_item_allowed_add_to_cart( $passed, $product_id, $quantity ) {
    
    $cart_contents    =  WC()->cart->get_cart();
    $cart_product_ids = [];
    if(!empty($cart_contents))
    {
        foreach($cart_contents as $cart_item)
            $cart_product_ids[] = $cart_item['product_id'];
    }
    $cart_product_ids = array_unique( $cart_product_ids );

    if( count( $cart_product_ids ) >= 1 ) {
        if(in_array($product_id, $cart_product_ids)) { // same product id passed
            $passed = true;
        } else {
            // Set to false
            $passed = false;
            // Display a message
            wc_add_notice( __( "You can only add one product to your cart at a time.", "woocommerce" ), "error" );
        }
    }

    return $passed;
}
```

Any advice on what addition would be needed to my existing code to meet the above conditions?

Answer (score 0):

To prevent when a certain product is in the cart, no other product should be added to it, and when there are other products in cart, this product should not be added, you can use:

- `woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation` filter hook
- [WC_Cart::find_product_in_cart()](https://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_cartfind_product_in_cart/) function - which allows to check if product is in the cart and return cart item key.

So you get:

```php
function filter_woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation( $passed, $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id = null, $variations = null ) {
    // Add the specific product ID here
    $specific_product_id = 30;

    // Real product ID
    $product_id = $variation_id > 0 ? $variation_id : $product_id;

    // WC Cart
    if ( WC()->cart ) {
        // Get cart
        $cart = WC()->cart;
        
        // If cart is NOT empty
        if ( ! $cart->is_empty() ) {
            // Cart id
            $product_cart_id = $cart->generate_cart_id( $specific_product_id );

            // Find product in cart
            $in_cart = $cart->find_product_in_cart( $product_cart_id );

            // In cart & the current product ID does not match
            if ( $in_cart && ( $specific_product_id != $product_id ) ) {
                // Display an error message
                wc_add_notice( __( 'You cannot add another product, there is already a specific product in cart', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );

                // False
                $passed = false;
            // NOT in cart & the current product ID matches
            } elseif ( ! $in_cart && ( $specific_product_id == $product_id ) ) {
                // Display an error message
                wc_add_notice( __( 'You cannot add this product, there are already other products in cart', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );

                // False
                $passed = false;
            }
        }
    }

    return $passed;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'filter_woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 10, 5 );
```